# How to compare a 3 sets of data in order to sort out how 2 of these data influence the third one?

Tags: r, statistics, classification, pca

I have a 3 set data like this:

[image]

There is a tool to say what is the most important variable in the removal? Is pH or dosage? I was thinking in a PCA (principal component analysis) however I'm a little lost

Comment: I would start with a simple linear model. but in order to that you have to lay down your hypothesis and test it.

Comment: @Mouad_S How is that linear model that you are proposing?

Comment: PCA will be a very complex way to do it and it's mostly used for different kinds of objectives. You have to be more specific when you say "important" variable. You can find out which variable is more correlated with `Removal`, or which one can best predict `Removal`. Run a regression model and see which one is a statistically significant predictor. Or run a more complicated model (like a random forest) and obtain the importance of each variable. There are many ways to it, because your question is very broad.

Comment: `your_model <- lm( Removal ~ Dosage + Ph, data = your_data_frame);
summary(your_model)`

Comment: Please do not post images.  No one can then easily copy and paste the data to their session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things to try.

From the plot it seems clear that Dosage (column 2) is more closely related to Removal (column 3) than pH (column 1).

Also Dosage has a 61% correlation with Removal whereas pH has a correlation of only -14%.

Neither variable is statistically significant in the lm summary output likely because of the small amount of data.

Stepwise regression based on AIC chooses the Removal ~ Dosage model.

(continued after graph)

```
matplot(scale(DF), type = "o")
```

[image: screenshot]

```
cor(DF)
##                 pH    Dosage    Removal
## pH       1.0000000 0.0000000 -0.1418573  <-- -14%
## Dosage   0.0000000 1.0000000  0.6091517  <-- 61%
## Removal -0.1418573 0.6091517  1.0000000

summary(lm(Removal ~., DF))

## Call:
## lm(formula = Removal ~ ., data = DF)
## 
## Residuals:
##      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
## -15.5556  -7.0556  -4.8889   0.7778  25.7778 
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)   69.056     39.047   1.769    0.127  
## pH            -2.833      6.362  -0.445    0.672  <-- not significant
## Dosage        12.167      6.362   1.912    0.104  <-- not significant
## 
## Residual standard error: 15.58 on 6 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.3912,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1883 
## F-statistic: 1.928 on 2 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.2257

fm <- step(lm(Removal ~., DF))
## ...snip...

fm
## Call:
## lm(formula = Removal ~ Dosage, data = DF)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)       Dosage  
##       52.06        12.17
```

**Note:** The input data in reproducible form is:

```
DF <- structure(list(pH = c(5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7), Dosage = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L), Removal = c(50, 60, 70, 50, 
90, 95, 50, 55, 58)), .Names = c("pH", "Dosage", "Removal"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It seems as though `Dosage` should be treated as a `factor`?

Comment: Maybe or maybe it just means no drug, standard dosage and twice standard dosage.  Also note that `Removal ~ factor(Dosage)` has a worse AIC than `Removal ~ Dosage`.

Comment: valid point my friend